# kafka + Error in fetch Kafka.server exception

Tags: apache-kafka

We have 5 brokers Kafka machines , brokers are installed on RHEL 7.6 machines

Broker version - version `0.10`

Cluster.Replication factor is 3. and this is production Kafka

Brokers IDS are

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

We observed following logs in Kafka `server.log` from all brokers

From the `server.log` we can see many lines of  `Error in fetch Kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread` exception.

```
[2023-11-24 12:51:48,991] WARN [ReplicaFetcherThread-6-4], Error in fetch kafka.server.b$FetchRequest@2149d051 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to 4 was disconnected before the response was read   
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$$anonfun$blockingSendAndReceive$extension$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:115)
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$$anonfun$blockingSendAndReceive$extension$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:112)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
```

It seems to me that each Kafka broker cant see her replica ,

Or Kafka cant sync with the replica data on other broker ,

**am I right** ?

also we can see from the logs that "`kafka.utils.NetworkClient`" is involved here